# Thread not acquiring available mutex

Tags: c, mutex

The following is a bit of output from gdb. It seems to me that the thread running here is not actually acquiring the lock.

```
120     pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_p->lock);
(gdb) p queue_p->lock->__data->__owner
$45 = 0 //This makes sense; the instruction hasn't run yet.
(gdb) n
121     if (queue_p->back == NULL) {
(gdb) p queue_p->lock->__data->__owner
$46 = 0 // What?
```

There are no other threads running when this happens. It's just a single line of code, but it's not operating the way I expect. Which probably means my expectations are wrong. Can anyone un-befuddle me?

EDIT: Hoping this may be of use to others. What I missed is that the main thread continues execution after it creates threads. This is obvious to me now, but at the time I posted this question, I was under the influence of a lifetime spent writing single-threaded procedural code.

So my code created threads, each of which attempted to acquire this mutex. But before they could, the main thread had run its course, which included destroying the mutex. I was focussed on the code shown and didn't fully comprehend that it wasn't the only code running.

Comment: The mutex type is opaque; you are not expected to look at (let alone understand) its contents.  That some field doesn't contain the value expect does not necessarily mean that the mutex is not locked.  It may just mean you don't understand what the mutex structure contains.  Since you've not identified which platform you're working on, it is hard to be definitive about your misunderstanding.

Comment: A MCVE showing the mutex initialized would have given more confidence in your assertion but, neverheless, what @JonathanLeffler says applies.

Comment: Well, it still seemed like the threads weren't getting the lock. Turns out the main thread was destroying the mutex without checking whether there were still any other threads running. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: `info threads` on gdb will tell you what other threads are doing, if any.